# Hibernate exception, "unexpected AST node"

Tags: java, hibernate

I am writing a rule query parser to parse through an if-then-else block to generate a typed query that be used to get a result set.
Here's a sample of the query I prepared:

```
select New com.sb.rule.service.dto.FoundObject(shipment.id) 
from Shipment shipment  
left join shipment.shipmentLines shipmentLines  
left join shipmentLines.itemDetail itemDetail  
left join shipment.fromAddress fromAddress  
left join shipment.toAddress toAddress  
where (
    ( 
        ( shipment.createDate = java.time.LocalDate.now().minusDays(1) )  
        and  
        ( itemDetail.uom = 'EACH' )  
        and  
        ( shipmentLines.itemNum = 'I1' )  
        and  
        ( shipmentLines.shipDate = java.time.LocalDate.now().plusDays(5) ) 
    ) 
    and 
    (
        ( fromAddress.country = 'IN' )  
        or  
        ( toAddress.country = 'IN' ) 
    )
)
```

I have even tried removing the additional brackets to changeteh query to :

```
select New com.sb.rule.service.dto.FoundObject(shipment.id) from com.sb.rule.domain.Shipment shipment  left join shipment.shipmentLines shipmentLines  left join shipmentLines.itemDetail itemDetail  left join shipment.fromAddress fromAddress  left join shipment.toAddress toAddress  
where (  shipment.createDate = java.time.LocalDate.now().minusDays(1)   and   itemDetail.uom = 'EACH'   and   shipmentLines.itemNum = 'I1'   and   shipmentLines.shipDate = java.time.LocalDate.now().plusDays(5)  ) 
and (  fromAddress.country = 'IN'   or   toAddress.country = 'IN'  )
```

But I still get the same error.

When this query is executed:

```
log.debug("Sql Query being executed : " + sqlQuery);
TypedQuery<FoundObject> query = entityManager.createQuery(sqlQuery.toString(), FoundObject.class);
Set<FoundObject> foundObjectSet = new HashSet<FoundObject>(query.getResultList());
log.debug("Returning : " + foundObjectSet.toString());
```

I get the below exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected AST node: ( near line 1, column 339 [select New com.sb.rule.service.dto.FoundObject(shipment.id) from com.sb.rule.domain.Shipment shipment  left join shipment.shipmentLines shipmentLines  left join shipmentLines.itemDetail itemDetail  left join shipment.fromAddress fromAddress  left join shipment.toAddress toAddress  where (( ( shipment.createDate = java.time.LocalDat   e.now().minusDays(1) )  and  ( itemDetail.uom = 'EACH' )  and  ( shipmentLines.itemNum = 'I1' )  and  ( shipmentLines.shipDate = java.time.LocalDate.now().plusDays(5) ) ) and ( ( fromAddress.country = 'IN' )  or  ( toAddress.country = 'IN' ) ))]
        at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:133)
        at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:157)
        at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:164)
        at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:670)
        at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:686)
        at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:23)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:305)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy182.createQuery(Unknown Source)
        at com.sb.rule.service.business.EvaluateRule.queryRuleDefinition(EvaluateRule.java:146)
```

Any ideas, on what am I doing wrong is greatly appreciated.

Comment: definitely a wrong interpretation of a query. I think StringBuilder will be a good idea. It makes clean and readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are not using **parametrized queries**, but instead are trying to add the parameters directly to the queries.

You need to replace your parameters with names like this

```
select New com.sb.rule.service.dto.FoundObject(shipment.id) 
from Shipment shipment  
left join shipment.shipmentLines shipmentLines  
left join shipmentLines.itemDetail itemDetail  
left join shipment.fromAddress fromAddress  
left join shipment.toAddress toAddress  
where 
        shipment.createDate = :cd
        and
        itemDetail.uom = :uom
        and
        shipmentLines.itemNum = :inum 
        and
        shipmentLines.shipDate = :sd
    and (
        fromAddress.country = :fc
        or  
        toAddress.country = :tc 
    )
```

Then pass the parameters to the query:

```
java.time.LocalDate today = java.time.LocalDate.now();
List<FoundObject> lst = em.createQuery(hqlstring, FoundObject.class)
        .setParameter("cd", today.minusDays(1))
        .setParameter("uom", "EACH") // or variable, instead of constant
        .setParameter("inum", "I1") // or variable, instead of constant
        .setParameter("sd", today.plusDays(5))
        .setParameter("fc", "IN") // or variable, instead of constant
        .setParameter("tc", "IN") // or variable, instead of constant
        .getResultList();
```

Also you use way too many unnecessary round brackets

Comment: Thanks @coladict. Using the parameters resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have already recognized that the parser fails here, splitting the input wrong:

```
java.time.LocalDat   e.now().minusDays(1) )
```

So maybe you just give it a try with this trimmed query:

```
select New com.sb.rule.service.dto.FoundObject(shipment.id) from com.sb.rule.domain.Shipment shipment left join shipment.shipmentLines shipmentLines left join shipmentLines.itemDetail itemDetail left join shipment.fromAddress fromAddress left join shipment.toAddress toAddress where ( shipment.createDate = java.time.LocalDate.now().minusDays(1) and itemDetail.uom = 'EACH' and shipmentLines.itemNum = 'I1' and shipmentLines.shipDate = java.time.LocalDate.now().plusDays(5) ) and ( fromAddress.country = 'IN' or toAddress.country = 'IN' )
```

Comment: I still end up getting the same exception. When the following typed query is used, it works well.   select New com.sb.rule.service.dto.FoundObject(shipment.id) from Shipment shipment  left join shipment.shipmentLines shipmentLines  left join shipmentLines.itemDetail itemDetail  left join shipment.fromAddress fromAddress  left join shipment.toAddress toAddress  where ((( ( shipment.orgNum = 'ORG1' )  and  ( itemDetail.uom = 'EACH' ) ) and ( ( fromAddress.country = 'IN' )  or  ( toAddress.country = 'IN' ) )) and ( ( shipment.fromFacilityNum = 'DC11' )  and  ( shipment.orgNum = 'ORG1' ) ))